# cp -p command in ubuntu

Tags: cp

```
set series = usno
if ( ! -e ut1.${series}  ) \cp -p ~/gg/tables/ut1.${series}  .
```

I'm trying to grasp a script. I need to know that what cp -p command works in this script?

Comment: Read the manpage `man cp`..it is described precisely there..also your script has many issues....

Comment: from `man cp`: `p` or `--preserve`: preserve the specified attributes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the `cp` manpage:

```
--preserve[=ATTR_LIST]
       preserve the specified attributes (default: mode,ownership,time‐
       stamps), if  possible  additional  attributes:  context,  links,
       xattr, all

-p     same as --preserve=mode,ownership,timestamps
```

In other words, it will preserve more metadata than it would by default.